# App does not fill up device screen, nor does launch screen autorotate

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, xib

I have two problems that I suspect are inter related.

I have a universal app that supports both landscape orientations.  My app launches up (with an interface builder launch screen), and then a SKScene is displayed.  I have three big problems.

1. On ipads, and only on iPads (iOS 8, or 9) when the app loads up, all the images are missing from it leaving only the text.  Furthermore the display area for the launch screen is about a centimeter smaller then the actual device display. This is not a problem on iPhones
2. On ipads, and only on iPads (iOS 8, or 9) for some reason the entire app happens with a border around it.  The area on the screen my app occupies is smaller then the actual device.  This is not a problem on iPhones.
3. My app is set to auto rotate inside of the "shouldAutoRotate()" function.  However I can not get the launch screen to launch in the proper orientation.

I suppose you might be interested to see the following things:

Excerpts from viewController:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation
import GameKit
import CoreData
import iAd

extension SKNode {
    class func unarchiveFromFile(file : String) -> SKNode? {
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {
            var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
            var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

            archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
            let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! GameScene
            archiver.finishDecoding()
            return scene
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

class GameViewController:  UIViewController,  SceneTransitionDelegate, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate, ADBannerViewDelegate {


    var audioPlayers:[AVAudioPlayer] = []
    var sounds:[NSURL] = []
    var nextSongDelay:NSTimer = NSTimer()
    var currentSong:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    var disp:CGFloat = 0
    var starget:String = "HI"
    var soundEffects:[AVAudioPlayer] = []

    var rwidth:CGFloat = 0
    var rheight:CGFloat = 0
    var skView:SKView { return view as! SKView }
    //var skView:SKView { return view as! SKView }
    var iadp:Bool = false

    var ar:Bool = true
    var uord:Bool = false



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        theEssence = self
        launchAudio()
        //mediumRectAdView!.delegate = self;

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        if (isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce() == false)
        {
            defaults.setBool(false, forKey: "player")
        }


        if (defaults.boolForKey("Toothachepunlockiad") == true)
        {
            s_manualoverride.self = true
            iAdBanner.hidden = true
        }

        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        //skView.showsFPS = true
        //skView.showsNodeCount = true
        skView.showsPhysics = false
        delli = self
        authenticateLocalPlayer()

        iAdBanner.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.width, 50)
        iAdBanner.delegate = self
        bannerVisible = false
        iAdBanner.hidden = false

        ar = true
        self.shouldAutorotate()

        transitionToScene(Menu.self)


    }
    //SceneTransitionDelegate method
    func transitionToScene(sceneClass:Scene.Type) {
        playing = false
        var sizeRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame
        var width = sizeRect.size.width
        var height = sizeRect.size.height
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        let scene = sceneClass(size: skView.bounds.size)
        scene.size = CGSizeMake(width, height)
        rwidth = width
        rheight = height
        swidth = width
        sheight = height
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        scene.sceneDelegate = self

        skView.presentScene(scene)


    }

    func transitionToScene(sceneClass: Scene.Type, transitionAnimation: SKTransition)
    {
        playing = false
        var sizeRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame
        var width = sizeRect.size.width
        var height = sizeRect.size.height
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        let scene = sceneClass(size: skView.bounds.size)

        scene.size = CGSizeMake(width, height)
        rwidth = width
        rheight = height
        swidth = width
        sheight = height
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        scene.sceneDelegate = self
        skView.presentScene(scene, transition: transitionAnimation)
    }


    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return ar
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.rawValue)
        } else {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        if (playing == true)
        {
            println("MEMORY WARNING WE ARE DIEING")
            //fatalError("MEMORY WARNING WE AARE ALL GOING TO DIE")
        }
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        if(bannerVisible == false) {

            // Add banner Ad to the view
            if(iAdBanner.superview == nil) {
                self.view.addSubview(iAdBanner)
            }

            // Move banner into visible screen frame:
            UIView.beginAnimations("iAdBannerShow", context: nil)
            banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height)
            UIView.commitAnimations()

            bannerVisible = true
        }

    }

    func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
        if(bannerVisible == true) {
            // Move banner below screen frame:
            UIView.beginAnimations("iAdBannerHide", context: nil)
            banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height)
            UIView.commitAnimations()
            bannerVisible = false
        }

    }

    func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.paused = true

        return true
    }

    func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.paused = false
    }
}
```

Some things I have recently done that could have triggered this:
Added fabric crash reports
Added auto rotation to it

[image: Picture of it]

Comment: Can you check whether the project's or target's settings somehow are set for iphone only?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem on iPhone 6 Plus. Reason for that was missing loading images of that device's display size. Check whether you have loading image of all required sizes and orientations. As you can see in the picture, Xcode tells you what size particular image should be. Hope this will fix your issue.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I am using a interface builder file instead of a launch image.

Comment: @J.Doe I seem to remember a similar problem in one of my apps. If your deployment target is less than the "launch screen support" version, you may have to add the launch images. It may also be possible that the launch image files just have to be present. (I can't check right now, because I would have to review my git history for that project and I don't have enough time for that right now. But I am confident that I added dummy launch images to fix it.)